# Angular 1 Ctrl Function from Directive after app.run function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive for my menu. 
In the $rootScope I set the Company and the User Permission.
Depending on the selected company and the permission i render the menu.

I set the company and the User Permissions in the app.run Function. This works so far, but sometimes the menu directive is rendered before the service call is finished.
Is there a possibility to render the menu directive after the Service Get Call is finished?

Thanks

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http, $stateParams, $state, $q,  goliathCompanyCheck)
{
....
....
....
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    var company_id = toParams.company_id;
    if (company_id) {
        var perm = goliathCompanyCheck.get({object: company_id},
            function(response){
                if (!response || !response.status || response.status == 'ERROR') {
                    $state.go('company_selector');
                }
                $rootScope.currentCompany = response.data.company;


            },
            function(response){
                $state.go('company_selector');
            });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: just to be clear...the code you're showing isn't setting permissions and company name in the app.run, but is instead wiring up an event listener to '$stateChangeStart' event, which is what really sets permissions and company name when that event fires.

Comment: @TSmith yes the $stateChangeStart function is the function which sets the permission.
It's declared insitde of the app.run function.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using UI-Router for this instead of doing it on the rootscope in your run block.

This allows you to specify it as a dependency for your view. That way your view will not load unless CurrentCompany is resolved, otherwise a state change failure will be triggered.

In this example your state 'app' is your base state for your application and requires a company id in the url so that you can resolve CurrentCompany for the view. In app.html you could have all of the markup and directives for your menu component and your pages can be child views of the 'app' state meaning they all have access to the CurrentCompany dependency as well.

Check out the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/:companyId/'
                templateUrl: 'app.html',
                controller: 'AppCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    //State won't resolve until CurrentCompany does
                    CurrentCompany: function ($stateParams, goliathCompanyCheck) {
                        return goliathCompanyCheck.get({object: $stateParams.companyId});
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.home', {
                url: 'home/',
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
    })
    .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, CurrentCompany) {
        //CurrentCompany gets injected into the controller and you can assign it to scope
        $scope.CurrentCompany = CurrentCompany;
    })
    .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, CurrentCompany) {
        //Can inject it into the child state as well if you want
        //but it's still available on the scope if the view is nested
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. But the menu is generated in a different controller and service. Inside of the Service MenuService is the prepareMenu function. I tried it with you solution but if i log the $scope.CurrentCompany inside of the service functions whichs generates the menu depending on the permission I get an undefined. 
Because the directive is rendered before the currentCompany is set

Comment: this is my service `angular.module('goliath.menu.services', []).
service('$menuItems', function($rootScope)` The solution would work if the directive service would be run after the currentCompany is set

Comment: You can't access $scope inside of a service unless you pass it in. You would have to call `MyService.prepareMenu($scope.CurrentCompany);` in your directive controller or link function. Then you can access CurrentCompany as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks but this solves not the problem, that the directive is rendered bevore the $scope.CurrentCompany is set.

Comment: Is your directive inside the view that resolves CurrentCompany? That shouldn't happen.

Comment: The resolve method is in the app state this is the parent state of states. 
And the directive is inside of another state.But the states are inherited from the app state.